# How to break meta values into different items and avoid duplicates?

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, meta-value

I'm trying to build a filter for a custom post type page. The custom post type has a metabox that allows inputting of different authors.

I am displaying the post names in a dropdown like this, using the get_post_meta:

```
/*Get the Authors*/
$list_authors = array(
'post_type'         => array('publications'),
);
$authors = array();
$query_authors = new WP_Query( $list_authors );

if ( $query_authors->have_posts() ) :
while ( $query_authors->have_posts() ) : $query_authors->the_post();
$author = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'cl_pub_authors', true);
if(!in_array($author, $authors)){
$authors[] = $author;
}
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
foreach( $authors as $author ):
?>
<option value="<?php echo $author;?>"><?php echo $author;?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The problem is that some values are grouped together, typed separated by commas. I need to take every value in the field as individual, and avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a basic php array question - not a WP question.

```
function unique_authors ( $authors ) {
    $newArray = array();

    foreach( $authors as $item ) {
        $itemArray = explode( ", ", $item );
        $newArray = array_merge($newArray, $itemArray);
    }

    $newArray = array_unique($newArray);
    return $newArray;
}

$authors = unique_authors( $authors );

foreach( $authors as $author ):  //etc
```

Comment: The problem is that my dropdown is displaying the authors as entered in the custom metabox that allows different values so some will display: Name1, Name2, Name 3 in a line, then another line with Name 1 then another line with Name 2 and so on if people chose only one in the meta value. But the issue is with multiple ones - need to break them into separate values and not repeat if used in different combinations :O

Comment: Yikes. So the real problem is the metabox.  Forcing people to input uniform data is always tough.  You could use jquery to show a single input field + a button to add another author input field.  Juggling the data after input is never very feasible.

Comment: I have a metabox that allows the user to select published posts from a custom post type. The metabox itself needs to behave this way. The user selects from posts there. I need to break the multiple posts selected there to different items in my query :c

Comment: Show us the data that you need to process into 'different items'

Comment: How do I show you the data? I tried using the print_r but it doesn't show anything at all :/

Comment: Try: `echo '<pre>'; var_dump( $query_authors ); echo '</pre>';`

Comment: Ok, I think I was placing it in a stupid place inside the select that'ts why it wasnt working ._. haha!... When var_dump $authors (the data I need to break down) it shows the right data (updating question with it)

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: thank you very much! I'm actually stupid and this answers the question, but the metabox I needed was another one (not the one I have been calling)....I will edit my question to match the answer, remove the name of people (sensitive data)